# Why does MSVC 2019 fail when returning a statically-sized array in a ternary?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I am trying to compile some [library code](https://github.com/facebookincubator/fbjni/blob/00330b41e6ca873bc2dfed377a87b013eebba931/cxx/fbjni/detail/SimpleFixedString.h#L102-L112) and ran into an error; I simplified the example and I have the following MVCE which fails to compile with MSVC 2019 with the error

> error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'const char (&)[20]'

```
static constexpr const char somethingWeird[] = "Well, that's odd...";
void fail() { throw 0; }

// This doesn't work
constexpr const char(&checkNullTerminatedGood(const char(&a)[20]))[20]{
  return a[19] == char(0) ? decltype(a)(a) : (fail(), decltype(a)(a));
}
static constexpr const auto somethingElseNew = checkNullTerminatedGood(somethingWeird);
```

When I convert the ternary operator to a proper if-statement, the code compiles well:

```
static constexpr const char somethingWeird[] = "Well, that's odd...";
void fail() { throw 0; }

// This works
constexpr const char(&checkNullTerminatedGood(const char(&a)[20]))[20]{
  if (a[19] == char(0)) {
    return decltype(a)(a);
  } else {
    return (fail(), decltype(a)(a));
  }
}
static constexpr const auto somethingElseNew = checkNullTerminatedGood(somethingWeird);
```

Is this a bug in MSVC? The first snippet compiles with GCC and Clang.

Comment: did you try without your *noexcept* ? `fail()` does `throw 0;` ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure there is better way to do it then your attempt. For me this is classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Same thing, @bruno. Will remove it from the MVCE.

Comment: @MarekR I don't think this is an XY problem; as I stated: I am compiling someone else's code on MSVC and it is failing. My question is literally: is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Since it compiles fine on the other Big 2, it seems a fine question to me regardless of noisy quibbling about the form of the MCVE. If anyone can minimise it further, they should do so! That'd make for an even clearer bug report if one does not already exist.

Comment: yes this is defiantly a bug of MSVC (it silently performed unwanted decay of array to a pointer) (a bit [simpler example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5zP6s)), but also I would not trust that code and prefer some alternative. Which version of C++ can you use?

Comment: A [mcve] is something like `char x[42]; static_assert(sizeof(true?x:(0,x))==sizeof(x));`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. not relay comma operator is not problem here. From my experiments problem is caused by function argument used in ternary operator: https://godbolt.org/z/P4bsaT if anything else is used in ternary operator it works fine on MSVC.

Comment: @MarekR this fragment exhibits abnormal behaviour to me, so it is a problem as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=msvc%20bug%20ternary%20operator%20array%20decay) shows this is [know problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/5527/c-overly-aggressive-decay-of-static-array-to-point.html) which is claimed to be fixed (but it is not).

[C++ Overly aggressive decay of static array to pointer in ternary operator - Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/5527/c-overly-aggressive-decay-of-static-array-to-point.html)

> #### Solution
>
> by [Leo Zhang [MSFT]](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/users/2978/59b35fef-2d81-43c7-b62e-b785cc15b6d0.html)    Sep 07, 2017 at 02:35 AM
>
> [image: avatar image]
>
> Thank you for your feedback! This issue has been fixed and it will be available in the next update to Visual Studio 2017. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!”

Comment: So it seems like it hasn't _actually_ been fixed. :-)

Comment: that is funny that report includes exact same code :).

Comment: I'm guessing they were also working on the library in the question, but I'm not positive. :-) I had seen this issue before and used some of it's code as a reproducer - seems like it's still an issue, though.